# Error in actual number of apis in wso2 api manager (4.0 version)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I found one error.
The actual registered API and the number shown below are different.
In fact, there are 21 APIs registered, and 23 are displayed as shown below.

Do you know to which table the data is referenced and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking inside the debase, use the Product Admin Rest API to see where the confusion is -

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/admin-apis/admin-v2/admin-v2/